# Persistence specification testing with fluent nhibernate mappings

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, foreign-keys

I've recently been playing around with fluent nhibernate & more specifically persistence specification testing.

However, I keep running into a sql lite error while running a relatively simple test with nunit when building the schema for the test on this line: (SessionSource.BuildSchema(Session)).

> System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteException : SQLite error near "/": syntax
>   error

Seeking some some guidance on what I am doing wrong as I'm relatively new to fluent. Is there an easier way to troubleshoot this error message?

```
public class Contact
{
    public int Id { get; protected set; }
    // some other properties 
    public IList<Note> Notes { get; set; }
}

public ContactMapping()
{
    Not.LazyLoad();
    Id(m => m.Id).GeneratedBy.Identity();
    HasMany(x => x.Notes).KeyColumns.Add("ContactId");
}

public class Note
{
    public int Id { get; protected set; }
    public Contact Contact { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}

public NoteMapping()
{
    Not.LazyLoad();
    Id(m => m.Id).GeneratedBy.Identity();
    Map(m => m.Title).Not.Nullable().Length(250);
    Map(m => m.Description).Not.Nullable().Length(2500);
    References(x => x.Contact).Column("ContactId").Cascade.All();
}
```

Config:

```
public void SetupContext()
{
    var cfg = Fluently.Configure()
        .Database(SQLiteConfiguration.Standard
            .ShowSql()
            .InMemory
            );
    SessionSource = new SessionSource(cfg.BuildConfiguration()
                                            .Properties, PersistenceModel());
    Session = SessionSource.CreateSession();
    SessionSource.BuildSchema(Session);
}

private static PersistenceModel PersistenceModel()
{
    var model = new PersistenceModel();
    model.AddMappingsFromAssembly(typeof(Contact).Assembly);
    return model;
}
```

And finally the persistence test:

```
new PersistenceSpecification<Contact>(Session)
    .CheckProperty(c => c.Id, 1)
    .CheckProperty(c => c.First, "Coding")
    .CheckProperty(c => c.Last, "Quiz")
    .CheckProperty(c => c.Email, "mail@test.com")
    .CheckReference(c => c.Notes, new Note { Title = "Title", Description = "Description" })
    .VerifyTheMappings();
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should be using `CheckList` in the `PersistanceSpecification` class instead of `CheckReference` in the above code.

Comment: Thanks Cole, will keep that in mind. However, my problem is that the schema generation seems to be failing for some reason prior to the action test execution on this line: SessionSource.BuildSchema(Session)

Answer (score 1):

Well, I feel a little silly. One of the columns I had excluded from my initial post was DateTime field which had an incorrect default value set which in turn was generating invalid sql when building the schema.

Outputting the configuration of the table when building the schema highlighted my error.